# How to make combo box column selectable if ReadOnly property of the DataGridView set to true?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have DataGridView it's contains 4 columns, one of the column is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

In DataGridView I want to prevent user to delete, edit, add rows in data grid view,
so I set the ReadOnly property of the DdataGgridView to true.

My problem is that DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is not selectable because ReadOnly property is set true.

Any idea how can I prevent user to delete, edit, add rows in DataGridView control, but make DataGridViewComboBoxColumn selectable?

Comment: You can use the CellFormatting event to override how the cell is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Please read the following [artice](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/75f600aa-2e8b-4610-ac31-6b4a65d23065/datagridview-copypaste-and-read-only).

Its about make readonly, just the cells, not the whole DataGrid