# Combobox empty and doesnt dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, combobox

I created a combobox column in a datagridview. The problem is my combobox is empty, blank, and doesn't dropdown when i click on it. When i use the debuger, every properties and value are ok and the items exists and are link to the combobox. Please help me :(

Code : `

```
    public Repair()
    {
        Main pp = new Main();

        InitializeComponent();
        this.label4.Text = pp.label3.Text;

        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        SqlCommand command1 = maConnexion.CreateCommand();

        if (Program.UserType == "admin")
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference,  RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            command1.CommandText = "SELECT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE FComponent IS NOT NULL";

        }
        else
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference,  RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            command1.CommandText = "SELECT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";

        }

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        sda1.Fill(dt1);

        DataColumn dcIsDirty = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
        DataColumn dcIsDirty1 = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
        dcIsDirty.DefaultValue = false;
        dcIsDirty1.DefaultValue = false;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;


        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();



        /**ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList(); //{ "C-C", "C-O", "Absence composant", "Mauvaise valeur", "Mauvais sens", "Mauvais composant" };
        list1.Add("C-C");
        list1.Add("C-O");**/
        List<string> list1 = new List<string> { ("C-C"), ("C-O") };







        combo.HeaderText = "FaultCodeByOp";
        combo.DataPropertyName = "FaultCodeByOp";
        combo.DropDownWidth = 120;
        combo.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        combo.Width = 90;

        combo.DataSource = list1;





        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(combo);





        dt.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty);
        dt1.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty1);

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;



        maConnexion.Close();

        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
        dataGridView2.Columns[3].Visible = false;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;

            }
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                dataGridView2.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }




    }

    /**private DataTable GetDescriptionTable()
    {
        DataTable l_dtDescription = new DataTable();
        l_dtDescription.Columns.Add("FaultCodeByOp", typeof(string));

        l_dtDescription.Rows.Add("C-O");
        l_dtDescription.Rows.Add("C-C");
        l_dtDescription.Rows.Add("Absence de composant");
        l_dtDescription.Rows.Add("Mauvais composant");
        l_dtDescription.Rows.Add("Mauvais sens");
        l_dtDescription.Rows.Add("Mauvaise valeur");

        return l_dtDescription;
    }**/




    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();
        string Var1 = textBox1.Text;
        SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
        SqlCommand command1 = maConnexion.CreateCommand();


        if (Program.UserType == "admin")
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
            {

                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
                //command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailAndPass WHERE BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent";

                command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference, FaultCodeByOp, RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";
                command1.CommandText = "SELECT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum And FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
            {

                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardName", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", Var1 + "%");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", Var1 + "%");
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FComponent", Var1 + "%");
                //command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FailOnly WHERE (BoardName LIKE @BoardName OR Machine LIKE @Machine OR SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum OR FComponent LIKE @FComponent) AND ReportingOperator IS NULL  ";
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Message, FComponent, ReadValue, ValueReference, FaultCodeByOp, RepairingTime FROM FailAndPass WHERE  (SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum) AND ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL  ";
                command1.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Machine, BoardName, BoardNumber FROM FailAndPass WHERE (SerialNum LIKE @SerialNum) AND ReportingOperator IS NULL AND FComponent IS NOT NULL";
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            sda1.Fill(dt1);

            DataColumn dcIsDirty = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
            DataColumn dcIsDirty1 = new DataColumn("IsDirty", typeof(bool));
            dcIsDirty.DefaultValue = false;
            dcIsDirty1.DefaultValue = false;
            dt.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty);
            dt1.Columns.Add(dcIsDirty1);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
            maConnexion.Close();

            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Visible = false;

        }

    }


    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = true;
        }

    }

    private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection maConnexion = new SqlConnection("Server= localhost; Database= Seica_Takaya;Integrated Security = SSPI; ");
        maConnexion.Open();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {


            if ((row.Cells[6].Value != null) && (bool)row.Cells[6].Value)
            {

                SqlCommand command = maConnexion.CreateCommand();
                command = new SqlCommand("update FailAndPass set FaultCodeByOp=@Fault, RepairingDate=@RD, RepairingTime = @RT, ReportingOperator=@RO WHERE SerialNum=@Serial", maConnexion);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fault", row.Cells[4].Value != null ? row.Cells[4].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RD", DateTime.Today.ToString("d"));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RT", row.Cells[5].Value != null ? row.Cells[5].Value : DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RO", this.label4.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", this.textBox1.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
        }



        maConnexion.Close();
        this.Hide();
        Repair rep = new Repair();
        rep.Show();

    }

    private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Main ff = new Main();
        ff.Show();

    }

    /**private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.ColumnIndex > -1)
            {
                // Bind grid cell with combobox and than bind combobox with datasource.  
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell l_objGridDropbox = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

                // Check the column  cell, in which it click.  
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Contains("FaultCodeByOp"))
                {
                    // On click of datagridview cell, attched combobox with this click cell of datagridview  
                    dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = l_objGridDropbox;
                    l_objGridDropbox.DataSource = GetDescriptionTable(); // Bind combobox with datasource.  
                    l_objGridDropbox.ValueMember = "FaultCodeByOp";
                    l_objGridDropbox.DisplayMember = "FaultCodeByOp";

                }


            }

     }**/
   }`
```

Comment: Share XAML code, check output window for any binding errors. See if data context is set correctly.

Comment: What is XAML code ? I'm programming in C#. I don't have any errors in the output window. Datasource, bindings, are set correctly.

Comment: up to now I used your code without loading any data from the DB but simply using an empty `DataTable`, but I cannot reproduce your error. My combobox has values and drops down

Comment: Why `AddRange` even `combo` is not an array.

Comment: How ? i dont have any dropdown and values. Addrange because i used arraylist in my exemple but now i've tried something else so i've putten it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that setting the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to `ReadOnly` evokes this error in the loop:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;

    }
}
```

I am trying to find out why exactly..... for now avoid setting it to `ReadOnly` with a simple `if` clause:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (!(dataGridView1.Columns[i] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn))
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The Problem seems to be `dataGridView1.Columns[0]`. This column does not like it to be set with values or to be set to `ReadOnly`. It also seems not to have any name (tested it) which is very weird. Nontheless, if you start your loop at `1` the error will go away and you can have even your `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to be set to `ReadOnly = true` without the `if` clause:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: But it is not in ReadOnly. My combobox is the last column in my datagridview which is the 6 column. So the combobox is always  ReadOnly = false because of my loop ?

Comment: actually it does not makes really sense how you set the readOnly to true. Because in every row you set the entire column to true. It would suffice to run through the columns collection

Comment: Okay wtf. I don't get it, It's working. My combobox is dropping down normally and i can choose my values. But why is the ReadOnly property true?

Comment: I don't really get it, the problem also arises, when I set only the first column at `dataGridView1.Columns[0]` to true (which is in my case the `dcIsDirty1` column. and the dropdown stops. But when I run with the loop at least until the ComboBox-column then it works!

Comment: Yes because i wanted the first 3 columns to be lock and not modify by the user. But in my loop i've specify that after the third one, all the columns should be editable. Maybe the datagridviewComboboxColumn is not count as a datagridview.Columns ?

Comment: This is mind-blowing. I think it may be because of the properties of the datagridview which doesn't affect others objects even if it is IN the datagridview and AS a column. So in fact, when i'm doing some changes on the datagridview properties it doesn't affect or inherit the datagridviewcolumncombobox?

Comment: this is a weird bug. I have found this [similiar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24101266/5174469) but the answer is not very helpful. What I don't understand is why it does not drop down when setting only the first column to read only but it does when setting only one more!

Comment: I found something: the problem is the the Column[0] is weird it has no name, and if you start your loop at position 1 the error will be gone! I am trying to find out what this strange column is

Comment: @AlexisRin I made an edit, the problem is the first column which is there, but it is not the one that you see or expect it to be. It is also impossible to set a value there, please try this line before the loop `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = whatEverTypeIsInYourDataTable`.

Comment: Okay i see. So the problem come from the column[0] which is kind of special because it does not accept readOnly property or values right ?

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help ! I wouldn't have been able to find the solution correctly.

Comment: @AlexisRin it seems that the only effect of setting the readOnly property to true in the first column is your bug! :D I am glad I could help. Good fortune!

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys. I've done a new test.

Here is my test code :

```
        combo.DataSource = list1;

        if(combo.IsDataBound)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TRUE");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FALSE");
        }
```

It seems that combo.datasource = list1 have all my value ("C-C" and "C-O"). But when i launch the debugger or launch the application, the messagebox which appear is the second one where combo.isdatabound = false. Normally, it should be True?